# boto3 python generate pre signed url for a whole bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I am trying to give temporary download access to a bucket in my s3.

using boto3.generate_presigned_url(), I have only managed to download a specific file from that bucket but not the bucket itself.

is there any option to do so or my only option is to download the bucket content, zip it, upload it, and give access to the zip?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cycling through the list of items in the bucket?

do a `aws s3 ls <bucket_name_with_Presigned_URL>` and then use a for loop to get each item.

Hope this helps.